# Code not compiling - casting

Tags: java

Commented code below are the reasons I think the code is not compiling, is this correct ?

```
class Building {

}


public class Barn extends Building{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Building build1 = new Building();
        Barn barn1 = new Barn();
        Barn barn2 = (Barn)build1;

        /**
         * Object is not a Building
         * Building is an Object
         */
        Object obj1 = Object(build1);

        /**
         * String is not a Building
         */
        String str1 = String(build1);

        /**
         * Building is not a Barn
         * Barn is a Building
         */
        Building build2 = Building(barn1);
    }

}
```

Inserted comments are my own. Why the two down-votes, I just didn't realize the casting syntax was incorrect.

Comment: This code is not valid Java code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is a SCJP question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to cast, no it is not correct. Casting in Java is done via

```
   Classname objectname =  (ClassName) src;
```

If you are trying to construct new objects, you need constructors and and you do it via

```
   Classname objectname = new Classname(constructorArg1, constructorArg2);
```

Finally, if you want the String representation of an object, you use

```
   String string = objectname.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the casting syntax is incorrect, it should be

```
Foo foo = (Foo)bar;
```

where you have:

```
Foo foo = Foo(bar);
```

Syntax notwithstanding:

- You try to cast a Building to Barn - this is incorrect. A Barn *is* a
  Building but a Building is not a Barn.
- You try to cast a Building to an Object. This would be fine.
- You try to cast a Building to a String. This is incorrect.
- You try to cast a Barn to a Building - this would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The class building doesn't has a constructor that takes the arguments "Barn".
Make this constructor to fix:
`public Building(Barn barn) {

// put your codes here

}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Object obj1 = Object(build1);
```

Won't compile. There is no method `Object()`.

```
Object obj1 = (Object) build1;
```

Should compile. You have the same problem 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, constructing object should looks like this:

```
YourClass ref = new YourClass();
```

Secondly, Try check in javadoc how constructors looks like for: [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#Object%28%29), [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Notice also that `Building` has only default constructor, so only this will work:

```
Building b = new Building();
```

Answer (score 0):

multiple problems:

1. build1 is not a Barn, its a Building. If you need a Barn, it should be declared as follows
   `Building build1 = new Barn();`
2. Every instance is an object anyways, what exactly are you trying with `Object obj1 = Object(build1);`? I guess you just need `Object obj1 = build1;` (why you need it is beyond understanding from the code sample offered in the question)
3. Objects can be converted to strings using toString(), so your code should be `String str1 = build1.toString();`
4. Finally, I don't truely understand what you mean to do with `Building build2 = Building(barn1);` but if you need to clone, you could write a constructor or implement a method that can clone.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the assumption that commented code is the reason why code is not compiling. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to cast to Object or String you should have

```
    Object obj1 = (Object) build1;             // This is OK, because all classes are 
                                               // considered to extend Object class
    String str1 = build1.toString();           // You can not cast to String, because
                                               // neither of your classes extend String class
                                               // But you can use the toString() method
                                               // that is defined in Object class

    Building build2 = (Building) barn1;        // This is OK, because Barn class extends
                                               // Building class
```

Casting syntax from C++ ClassName(object) is not present in Java, only old style C casting syntax is (ClassName) object.
Hope this helps.